# Print CSS - Page break in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, page-break-inside

I recently stuck in this issue where chrome is behaving wierdly and not obeying any CSS rules.

In my page, I have big sections which I don't want to break while printing.
Below is the code

```
body.index .section{
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    -webkit-region-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

It works nice for all other browser except CHROME.
In chrome, it looks like
[image]

Red section shows the div breaking.

PS: I blured the page just avoid any problem.

Comment: you may not have a choice, since chrome picks the paper size for you and  seems to decide on its own how much fits in that paper?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position: relative` to the section.

```
body.index .section{
    position:relative;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    -webkit-region-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if you've figured anything out with this. I'm having a similar problem. No matter what I do, I can't get Chrome to respect `page-break-inside` on images or paragragraphs.